# How to clear ComboBox Text

Tags: vb.net, combobox

when i use `ComboBox1.Items.Clear()` it clears all the items in the combobox and when i use `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1` it doesn't show any text and when i choose any of the entry, it doesn't show, it's blank.

this is my code to show my database fields into a ComboBox, and

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form4

Dim con As New MySqlConnection
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;database=db")
    Try
        con.Open()

        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', cfname, cmname, clname,'from', cparty,'party') as names, " & _
                       "cpos, cid from candidate WHERE cpos='President'"
With ComboBox7
            Dim dv6 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='President'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "names"
            .ValueMember = "names"
            .DataSource = dv6
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Well unless you've wiped all that from the db, you should unbind the combo from the data. Whole point of data bound controls is you manipulate the data it's bound to and the control shows it.

Answer (score 2):

> How to clear ComboBox Text

You should use:

```
ComboBox1.ResetText()
```

Or else:

```
ComboBox1.Text = String.Empty
```

Answer (score 2):

While setting the text to `""` might work, it will only clear the text and if your combo box populates some text boxes then these will remain with the previous values. Try:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = Nothing
```

This will also work if your combo box is grayed out such that you can't type anything into it.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Forms and WPF, you can say:

ComboBox1.Text = String.Empty